# I need a quality linux UK based webhost

Tags: linux, looking-for-hosting, dedicated-hosting, reseller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Can any suggest a good (ideally) UK based reseller web host. I don't want the cheapest solution. I want a robust, quality one. Needs to run php5 and MySQL.

I have been considering a managed dedicated server instead of a reseller account so if anyone has good experiences please let me know.

Comment: The next time, ask for an offer on http://www.webhostingtalk.com/, this is not a shopping site.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I disagree on this, hosting is extremely related with webmaster, but let's not discuss this here, there is an appropriate question on meta: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104/is-a-question-about-web-hosts-appropriate/529#529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Rackspace http://www.rackspace.co.uk/

Comment: I heard good things about Rack Space. Probably one of my top choices at the moment. I do like the sound of PZPC offering WHMCS though!

Comment: I'm still striving to understand what is the price for RackSpace plan. IMHO they are not transparent about prices.

Answer (score 2):

[EZPZHosting](http://ezpzhosting.co.uk/)

PHP: 5.2.15

MySQL: 5.0.92-community

Call 0800 862 0331 and ask to speak to Dan (Say Hedley recommended you).

Quality service, superb support (they also offer white label support via *your* WHMCS customer portal so you can offer 24/7 support to your customers) and excellent prices.

I have been happy as a pig in muck since moving to these guys. They also offer a free WHMCS licence with their reseller package which is a godsend and a huge saving on a lot of the other companies around there. WHMCS allows you to manage your entire billing & invoicing, domain registration, support ticket system and knowledgebase.

They were and may still  be running a 25% off and free upgrade to next level offer on one of the Web Hosting forums which I can't remember just now but can hunt for it if you are interested?

**EDIT:** [webhosting.com](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/) is where you might still find the offer. You have to create an account first to be able to see the offers section but it is well worth it.

Comment: May we ask where were you hosting your stuff before?

Comment: PART 1: Of course you can. It was with a company called LiquidSix. They are windows based and use Helm as the Control Panel which is dreadful and no longer supported so very bereft of features. It took me 2 months of research and testing to finally end up with EZPZ and I tried a lot of hosts during my research as most of them give you 30 days trial/money back.

Comment: PART 2: I would set up an account with one then either move a domain over or just test it before finding something I wasn't happy with and then moving on to the next one. For instance some charge to transfer in .co.uk domains, some failed to set my account up as their automated system failed and I walked away. Non of them offered WHMCS bundled in for free so that was going to add quite a lot to the monthly price.

Comment: thanks for reply. You moved more than just hosting, you passed from Windows + Helm to Linux + cPanel hosting. Of course you have been happy as a pig in a muck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud hosting are very on fashion now, but IMHO I've never been able to understand on their site how much I'm going to spend for a simple hosting plan.

Some hosters not selling *clouds*, but selling plans with a monthly/yearly price written loud and clear on their websites are:

- http://www.eukhost.com server really in UK, I tried to ping them from UE and I'm using their services. I can't say I'm unhappy, some downtimes yes, but I bought the absolute cheapest plan, so it might be that more expensive plans work better.
- http://www.webhostingbuzz.co.uk they told me their server is in Amsterdam, I never used their services, but when I try to ping them from UE the average response time does not seem to be of a server in Amsterdam, but more far away like a US server.
- http://www.hostcoloreurope.com/ their server is in Portugal, but still near enought to UK and your vistors will never notice the difference in response time. The major advantage of this hosting seems to be that it's a US based company with a branch server in Portugal. I noticed for webhsoting that US customer service seems to be generally better than European ones. At least regarding response time. Anyway I did not try this hoster yet, except for asking some pre-sales questions, so I can not say anything except that I'm planning to try soon.
- http://www.webhost.uk.net/ (when asking pre-sales questions to them, even via chat, they are transparent in replies about everything and they know and explain technical details. I had the feeling they know what they are doing. So far I tried only their cheapest plan for few months, so I can't say yet). The only funny thing is there is another hoster with simial name WEBHOST.UK.COM that show up 1st page on Google.uk when searching for "cpanel web hosting"

---

**UPDATE:**

**eukhost.com got worst and worst, continuous downtimes** I complained and also bought a more expensive plan so I should be supposed to get a better uptime, but nothing! I'm definitely gonna change and find a new webhoster in EU soon.

And last but not least they just came up with a news today saying tehy will turn off PHP `mail` function for all their plans starting form July/29th/2011. I still can't believe it's true.

Comment: What is eUKhost's support like?

Comment: @BWRic: support got slower and slower as they probably increased the number of customers. They lately take up to 7 hours to reply to one simple support request.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me / this site updated. It's appreciated.